# Modify the default admin logo in Magento 2 (login portal and backend menu)

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, backend

I would like to change both **the logo in the login admin portal** and **the Magento icon** at the top left of the admin menu.

What is the easiest way to do that, according images I want to upload are PNG files (I am not familiar with SVG format) 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: To modify the default admin logo with custom theme, [check here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206125/61183).

Comment: To modify custom admin logos using module, [check here](https://github.com/theshreyas/magento-2-quickies/tree/main/Adminlogo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to change top left logo of the admin menu you have to create in your custom module `view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Page\Header" name="logo" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">logo</argument>
                    <argument name="edition" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Community Edition</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/custom-admin-icon.svg</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Place `custom-admin-icon.svg` with height 25px and width 41px into `CustomModule/view/web/images/custom-admin-icon.svg`

For the Admin Login page create new `view/adminhtml/layout/admin_login.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/custom-admin-logo.svg</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Feel free to use PNG files instead of SVG.

Comment: I placed my custom Icon in my custom module at the location you specified, but after uploading and clearing all caches, generation and pub/static, I only get the error image not found in pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images, so the generator is not placing the image where magento expects it to be.  I've followed your instructions exactly, could there be something missing?

Comment: Can you please provide full path of the image and full path of the layout file? Also, do you run in developer mode? Thanks

Comment: I have the image in the custom module at `app/code/Metal/Backend/view/web/images/logo_288x16.png` and the layout file is at `app/code/Metal/Backend/view/adminhtml/layout/admin_login.xml`. The file matches the block of code above except for the filepath in the argument, which is `images/logo_288x16.png`. This results is Magento correctly looking for my image, but it seems that magento expects it to be in the backend theme directory, not the custom modules, hence my confusion.

Comment: @MaxPronko can not we do it using custom theme or is it necessary to create custom module ? - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207833/magento-2-modify-default-admin-logo-login-and-backend-menu-with-custom-theme

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 small changes in 'Max Pronko' module:

1) Add `Namespace_Modulename` before image path

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename/images/custom-admin-logo.svg</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

2) And change directory: `CustomModule/view/web/images/custom-admin-icon.svg`

to

```
CustomModule/view/adminhtml/web/images/custom-admin-icon.svg
```

Comment: Hello @Gmb, I have created both files in my custom module and also update your changes and clean cache also but still showing magento logo.