# Magento 2 - Modify default Admin Logo (login and backend menu) with Custom Theme

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, theme, backend, custom-theme

After creating my custom storefront theme, I am now trying to modify the default magento admin logo with custom theme(**the logo in the login admin portal and the Magento icon at the top left of the admin menu**). Below are the steps followed.

**Custom Theme Logo uploaded at**

```
app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[Themename]/web/images/logo.png
```

**app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[Themename]/registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'adminhtml/[VendorName]/[Themename]',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[Themename]/theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Custom Theme Title</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent>
</theme>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[Themename]/Magento_Backend/layout/admin_login.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-login" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles" />
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/logo.png</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/[VendorName]/[Themename]/Magento_Backend/layout/default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header">
            <referenceBlock name="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="logo_image_src" xsi:type="string">images/logo.png</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="string">auto</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="string">auto</argument>
                    <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">logo</argument>
                    <argument name="edition" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Community Edition</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Create new custom module to apply Admin Theme

**app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">[VendorName]/[Themename]</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**CLI Commands executed**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**New DB entry for backend theme and custom module is also seen in `theme` and `setup_module` table respectively.**

How do I reflect admin theme changes ? Magento ver - 2.2.2

Comment: To modify custom admin logos using module, [check here](https://github.com/theshreyas/magento-2-quickies/tree/main/Adminlogo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create new module to apply an admin theme:**

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">[VendorName]/[themename]</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Does this mean apart from creating admin theme, one has to create module as well in order to reflect admin theme changes ?

Comment: @Vikram - Yes, new or existing module is require to [apply an admin theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_apply.html).

Comment: And what if I do not use custom admin theme and directly create custom module to add logo changes like its mentioned here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96945/modify-the-default-admin-logo-in-magento-2-login-portal-and-backend-menu ?
What is the difference in creating a custom admin theme and applying it using another custom/existing module OR directly creating custom/existing module to apply logo changes ? What could be the best approach and practice according to Magento standards ?

Comment: @Vikram - As per my suggestion, "creating a custom admin theme and applying it using another custom module" is a best practice. Because if you've more changes related to the admin theme, then it will easy to handle code-base as well as it will also be easy to manage static resources(CSS, JS, images, etc..). If you've only single change or creating extension  then you can go with module. Both are proper way, you can select any as per your requirement.

Comment: I have edited my question and extended for using custom module to apply admin theme. But I still do not see those logo changes being reflected.

Comment: @Vikram - Review my [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206100/magento-admin-logo-change) OR [magento2-admin-theme](https://github.com/manishjoy/magento2-admin-theme) try this same module.

Comment: I have already reviewed your answer and based on that implemented the same but the logo is still not loading

Comment: @Vikram - [magento2-admin-theme](https://github.com/manishjoy/magento2-admin-theme) download and try this module with default M2 setup.